# Typescript replaces JSX in a .tsx file with undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup

This is a confusing bug, I'm coming back to frontend work after a hiatus of over an year.

#### Setup and configuration

I am experimenting with rollup and react-runkit to create some docs for my backend typescript project.

**Typescript config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["src/docs", "typings"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**Rollup config**

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';


export default {
    input: 'src/docs/index.tsx',
    output: [
        {
            file: 'src/docs/dist/bundle.js',
            format: 'umd'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        typescript({
            tsconfig: './tsconfig.docs.json'
        }),
        resolve(),
        replace({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ]
}
```

**The React module in question**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import * as Embed from 'react-runkit';

function App() {
  const source = `console.log('Hello World');`;
  return (
    <div>
      <Embed source={source} />
    </div>
  );
}

console.log('Hello, World');
const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDom.render(<App />, app);
```

#### READ THIS (THE ERROR, THE CONCERNING PART) in the bundled output:

```
function App() {
      var source = "console.log('Hello World');";
      return (undefined("div", null,
          undefined(Embed, { source: source })));
  }
  console.log('Hello, World');
  var app = document.getElementById('app');
  undefined(undefined(App, null), app);
```

After a bit of digging, I find that when I include:

#### Option 1: Includes the React Source but not the JSX transform:

```
plugins: [
  resolve(),
  replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
  }),
  commonjs(),
  typescript({
    jsx: 'react',
   }),
 ]
```

gives me the react source in the `bundle.js` but leaves the `<div>` as `undefined`.

#### Option 2: Includes the React transform but not the react source:

```
plugins: [
  resolve(),
  replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
  }),
  commonjs(),
  typescript({
    jsx: 'react',
    module: 'CommonJS'
  }),
]
```

Comment: Are your dependencies installed? React, ReactDOM in this case.

Comment: @kushalvm Yes they are installed as dev-dependencies.